# Safely executing a function in a not-thread-safe class (Android Camera)

Tags: android

I'm using the callback `onPreviewFrame` for my application, but it causes problems when I try to exit the activity. Without the callback, clicking `back` has no issues, but with the callback, clicking `back` will alert me that a call has been made after `release()` on the camera object has been executed.

Note: the callback is threaded (I believe this is the default implementation), and continues to try to access the camera object after it's been killed.

How can I safely exit the activity without this callback causing me problems? If you'd like to see code I can post some.

Comment: I am not sure if this help try this by overriding back button on your activity http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#release%28%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems kind of ridiculous to me, but perhaps in the `onPause()` method where one would normally call

```
mCamera.stopPreview()
mCamera.release()
```

a callback should be set:

```
mCamera.stopPreview()
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null)
mCamera.release()
```

This assures us that no calls will be made to the camera once the preview has been destroyed. Seems to work..